# Laravel Cookies on test domain

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

I have a website which is on (**myapp.com**). Now I created a separate (digitalocean) webhosting (**test.myapp.com**) for my testing environment.

The issue is that the saved cookies, used by myapp.com, are also being used for my test.myapp.com.

#### How can I make sure my cookies are only being used by one domain? Is it good practice to do so?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show your `config/session.php`?

Comment: 'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null), So I'm guessing there is no domain attached to the sessions.

Comment: Does `SESSION_DOMAIN` have a value in your `.env` file?

Comment: Nope, I added it now on the testing server, does that mean everybody wil have to log off? Thanks for your time by the way.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's possible that all current cookies will be invalidated.

Comment: Hmh that's a big guess to take..

Answer (score 1):

You can [specify the domain](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Cookie/CookieJar.html#method_make) while creating a cookie. Here it is the fifth parameter. You can find it in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#cookies) as well.

If you use the `cookie()` helper function:

```
cookie('my-cookie', 'my-value', 0, null, 'myapp.com');
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your `domain` in `config/session.php` has no `.` in front of it, this makes the cookie work on all subdomains.

If the value is set to `null`, set it to the domain name for your website, including the subdomain if applicable.

Comment: it's set to null at the moment.